# jQuery Mobile - Footer - navbar - when rendering shows as three columns and two rows grid layout

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile, navigation, uinavigationbar

The page footer added as fixed icon based navbar. but when it come to display, naevbar converted to a grid layout. that is, three columns and two rows grid layout.

Following script I have used for footer nevBar,

```
    <div data-role="footer" class="nav-footer"  data-position="fixed"> 
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-footer" data-grid="d"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" id="home" data-icon="custom">H</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="messages" data-icon="custom">M</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="activities" data-icon="custom">A</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="trackers" data-icon="custom">T</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="settings" data-icon="custom">S</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

but it render as follows.

```
    <div class="nav-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer ui-footer-fixed fade ui-fixed-overlay" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo">
      <div class="nav-footer ui-navbar" data-grid="d" data-role="navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="ui-grid-b">
          <li class="ui-block-a">XXX</div>
          <li class="ui-block-b">...</div>
          <li class="ui-block-c">...</div>
          <li class="ui-block-a">...</div>
          <li class="ui-block-b">...</div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Content of each li as follows.

XXX ==>

```
 <li class="ui-block-a">
  <a id="home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-top ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="custom" href="#" data-theme="a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom"></span>
        <span class="ui-btn-text">H</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

My output shows as two rows and three colomns grid. Please can you find the reason.

Comment: Try to remove the  data-grid="d"? 
I dont get the point what you are trying to achieve or what the problem could be?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing data-grid="d" also, No luck yet.

Comment: I'm just expecting to get footer navigation bar with icons, and it is a fixed position. I have five links, so expect to get them horizontally, but bad luck it comes as two rows and three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> your items </div>
```

Comment: sorry cant read your comment, why do you have to code a lot? its just 2 lines more then before?

Answer (score 0):

You have specify the classes on your li elements to tell how many columns you want

```
<ul class="ui-grid-b">
   <li class="ui-block-a">XXX</div>
   <li class="ui-block-b">...</div>
   <li class="ui-block-c">...</div>
   <li class="ui-block-D">...</div>     <--D here, column 4
   <li class="ui-block-E">...</div>     <--E here, column 5
</ul>
```

Default number of columns is three I guess, which is why the last two were pushed to the next row.